# sending emails using Elmah

Tags: .net, smtp, elmah, error-logging

I have configured Elmah for my system and it logs error correctly. Now I want to configure the email module where it is able to send out emails when there is an error.

I have added following code to my web.config.  but it is not working. Please let me know if there is wrong with it:

```
<elmah>
      <errorMail
                 from="Fromaddress"
                 to="kunal@contestfactory.com"
                 subject="ERROR From Elmah:"
                 async="true"
                 smtpPort="587"
                 smtpServer="serverName"
                 userName="username"
                 password="Password" />
  </elmah>
```

Comment: Never mind. The only problem was Port number. It should be default 25 NOT 587. I am not sure why all the example did write port 587 even though SMTP default is 25 any suggestions?

Comment: Have a read of this http://mostlygeek.com/tech/smtp-on-port-587/ that should explain it.